# What are the code requirements for outdoor plumbing and electrical surface-level conduits?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, code-compliance, outdoor, nec

I'm planning to re-design my yard, and I'm looking to decouple the dependencies between contractors.

I am planning to add some outdoor appliances (e.g. hot tub, sauna) which would require adding new wiring from the panel to the appliances. At the same time, I want to change the grading of the soil and re-do the walk paths and surfaces where the appliances would rest. Lastly, I want to integrate a rainwater collection system which would require re-doing the sprinkler plumbing. As far as I can tell, this would introduce a dependency between the electrician, landscaper, and plumber which I want to contract separately.

One idea that I have to remove this dependency is to have the new water and electrical lines be in a conduit that is accessible from the surface. Here is a model of what I am imagining:

[image: Low fidelity model of a utility trench at surface level]

It is meant to be a trench at the surface level of the ground. It would house water and electrical lines that end up at outdoor spigots or outlets. The trench would have a removable top cover for ease of maintenance of the utility lines.

Then, I could just tell the landscapers to build the conduit, and I can have the electrician and plumber come in at a later time. In theory at least.

My questions to the community:

- Does this plan make sense? Or would the electrician and plumber have qualms about filling in the trench after the landscapers are done?
- What are the relevant code requirements in the United States for plumbing and electrical surface-level conduits like shown above?

Comment: Check with your local building department. Code requirements vary by location.

Comment: do the conduits before landscaping

Comment: It will work but will be more expensive. Also water and electric cables are meant to be at different depths, around here anyway.  I  would trench it to the deeper level required. Get the plumber to put in the electrical conduit with a draw wire. The electrician can then pull his cables through later.

Comment: Yes. Electrical conduits must be at a certain depth (18" of cover) post-landscaping, i.e. the landscaping isn't allowed to run them shallow.  And water pipes need to be at a certain depth. Climate change doesn't care what your historic freeze risk or freeze depth was.

Answer (score 2):

Most jurisdictions don't allow conduit to be installed by contractors not licensed as Electrical Contractors. I do not know code requirements for plumbing, the NEC does not prohibit electrical and plumbing in the same trench.

Conduit is either above grade or below. Above grade the NEC requires:

> **352.30 Securing and Supporting.** PVC conduit shall be installed as a complete system as provided in 300.18 and shall be fastened so that
> movement from thermal expansion or contraction is permitted. PVC
> conduit shall be securely fastened and supported in accordance with
> 352.30(A) and (B).
>
> **(A)Securely Fastened.** PVC conduit shall be securely fastened within 900 mm (3 ft) of each outlet box, junction box, device box,
> conduit body, or other conduit termination. Conduit listed for
> securing at other than 900 mm (3 ft) shall be permit‐ ted to be
> installed in accordance with the listing.
>
> **(B)Supports**. PVC conduit shall be supported as required in [Table 352.30](https://imgv2-1-f.scribdassets.com/img/document/344971450/original/e48e91b3b3/1658612727?v=1). Conduit listed for support at spacings other than as shown in Table 352.30 shall be permitted to be installed in accordance with the
> listing. Horizontal runs of PVC conduit supported by openings through
> framing members at intervals not exceeding those in Table 352.30 and
> securely fastened within 900 mm (3 ft) of termination points shall be
> permitted.

Below grade the NEC requires:

> **352.10(H) Underground Installations.** For underground
> installations, PVC shall be permitted for direct burial and
> underground encased in concrete.  See 300.5 and 305.15.
> [image]

(Section 305 applies to 1000+ volts.)